# Check if a string contains quote (")

Tags: vba, string, ms-word, character, special-characters

I want to search a string for a character. I'm using `InStr` and 
I want to return that character which will be passed to a user form.

My code works fine if I manually assign a string to a variable. For example:

```
ProtFunc = "21G_TRIP"""
```

The code will find the `"` and then return with a message box saying:

> Bad Character "

The problem comes when using a selection from the Word document. It finds the `"` but doesn't return the character.

See code below:

Note: Parts of the code I have seen used from various forums.

```
Sub CharFind ()

'For testing purposes
'ProtFunc = "21G_Trip"""
ProtFunc = Selection

'Checking the ProtFunc for invalid Characters
'This searches for invalid characters in the ProtFunc String and will inform    user of error


'Forsome reason the search picks up an additional character,
'the line below removes the last charater of the ProtFunc

'ProtFunc = Left(ProtFunc, Len(ProtFunc) - 1)


'The following characters will produce invalid file paths: \ / : * ? " < > |
'Additionally the following are checked too:     , . ;

 strTemp = ProtFunc

If (InStr(1, strTemp, "/") > 0) Or (InStr(1, strTemp, "") > 0) Or _
(InStr(1, strTemp, "*") > 0) Or (InStr(1, strTemp, "?") > 0) Or _
(InStr(1, strTemp, "|") > 0) Or (InStr(1, strTemp, """") > 0) Or _
(InStr(1, strTemp, "<") > 0) Or (InStr(1, strTemp, ">") > 0) Or _
(InStr(1, strTemp, ":") > 0) Then




'Assigning the invaild charater to be displayed
If (InStr(1, strTemp, ",") > 0) Then Char = "," Else
 If (InStr(1, strTemp, ".") > 0) Then Char = "." Else
  If (InStr(1, strTemp, ":") > 0) Then Char = ":" Else
   If (InStr(1, strTemp, ";") > 0) Then Char = ";" Else
    If (InStr(1, strTemp, "\") > 0) Then Char = "\" Else
     If (InStr(1, strTemp, "/") > 0) Then Char = "/" Else
      If (InStr(1, strTemp, "*") > 0) Then Char = "*" Else
       If (InStr(1, strTemp, "?") > 0) Then Char = "?" Else
        If (InStr(1, strTemp, """") > 0) Then Char = """" & BDBDBDB Else
         If (InStr(1, strTemp, "<") > 0) Then Char = "<" Else
          If (InStr(1, strTemp, ">") > 0) Then Char = ">" Else
           If (InStr(1, strTemp, "|") > 0) Then Char = "|"





MsgBox "Bad Character." & vbCr & Char

'Assigning the the invaild character to the ListBox in the User Form       ErrorMsgProtName
ErrorMsgProtName.ListBox1.AddItem (Char)
'Showing the User Form ErrorMsgProtName
ErrorMsgProtName.Show
'Clearing the ListBox in the User Form ErrorMsgProtName for the next round
ErrorMsgProtName.ListBox1.Clear

Else

MsgBox ProtFunc & "Is fine"

End If

'InvalChar Search - End



End Sub
```

Comment: What is `BDBDBDB` in the line  `Then Char = """" & BDBDBDB`?

Comment: Apologies that was just to see if the correct Char was being displayed in the Msgbox. Excuse my ignorance regex?

Comment: A regular expression. I showed an example in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word is probably using a "smart quote" instead of a standard quote:

```
”    Smart quote. Unicode hex value &H201D.
"    Standard quote. Unicode hex value &H22.
```

The smart quote is fine for use in a Windows path, so there's no need to remove it, unless you really want to.

BTW, a regex would make your life *much* easier:

```
Dim re
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "[\\/:\*\?""<>\|]"

If re.Test(strTemp) Then
    MsgBox "Bad Character." & vbCr & re.Execute(strTemp)(0)
Else
    MsgBox strTemp & " is fine"
End If
```

Comment: So the code re.Execute(strTemp)(0) provides the Bad Character?  which i could then store as a string and pass through to the UserForm? I see that word is using the smart quote in the document.

Comment: Yes. You could assign `re.Execute(strTemp)(0)` to a string variable to save the invalid character: `Char = re.Execute(strTemp)(0)`.

Comment: Great stuff, I appreciate the asssitance